# 1995 Volvo 850 Sedan Digital Instrument readings blnk

Tags: volvo

My Volvo 850has a new expensive  battery Temps have been very cold, single digits. I have not been driving it but starting it on the regular. Has been fine until it wouldn't start. I jumped it and got it going but now the digital clock display and info. is gone. Blank no digital readings at all! Warning lights work and speedometer. I checked the fuse, no corrosion and seems good. Is there a light in the cluster that is needed for the digital read out?? 
Thank you in advance.
Patti Jo

Comment: Hello thank you for your comment! I would start it and let it run for about 10 minutes I did not drive it as it was buried in about 3 feet of snow. After we jumped it I did drive it for about a half hour the display did not come on. I checked it this morning, battery is still charged the digital display is still blank, all the lights on the instrument panel are on and bright. What's also odd is that the radio will not accept the code. I put it in and rot, and is shows "off" on the screen. Patti Jo

Answer (score 0):

When you say « starting it on the regular » do you mean start it and run for 2 minutes then off or start it and do a 20 mile drive to get it warm?

To keep the battery charged if it is not getting long runs then you should consider a battery tender - this will keep the battery topped up without overcharging it.

If the car has got very cold, and it sounds possible, those displays are affected by temperature, so if you get the while car warm then the displays may well function again - I would not take them apart until you have got the car warm...